# Calling methods and properties from a sibling component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I have two components and when component A has clicked the component 2 should show (add a class). If it is a parent child component I can do it by calling a template reference variable. But in this case, it is not. They are siblings. I've tried many places but they only showed communicating data. What is the best method for this?

Comp-A HTML

```
<app-comp-a>
<button (click)="profilePanel.panelOpen()"></button>
<app-comp-a>
```

Comp-B HTML

```
<app-comp-b #profilePanel>
<div *ngClass="panelCss">
<p>panel opened</p>
</div>
<app-comp-b>
```

Comp-B TS

```
panelCss = 'hidePanel';

panelOpen(){
panelCSS = 'showPanel';
}
```

Comment: You can solve this by using service (for instance - SharedService), your panelOpen() function and panelCss property should be written in that service, your two components should inject that service and when you change panelCss property you can see that prop from every component that injects the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a service where you have a variable of type `Subject`. With this variable you will be able, in your component B, to wait for component A to send something.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SiblingServiceService {

  showSibling = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

}
```

`showSibling` is your Subject where you can wait for data in component B

**component A**

```
import { theService } from 'path/to/service'

...

export class SiblingAComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: theService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openPanel(){
    this.service.showSibling.next(true);
  }
}
```

**component B**

```
import { theService } from 'path/to/service'

...

export class SiblingBComponent implements OnInit {

  active: boolean = false;

  constructor(private service: theService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openPanel(){
    this.service.showSibling.subscribe(res => {
      this.active = res
    });
  }
}
```

[Here a stackblitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hghmq4)

Comment: Thank you for this really simple example. This saved my day.